# How do I send the end of file character to an ssh connection programmatically

Tags: bash, ssh, eof

I would like to simulate this shell session:

```bash
$ ssh remotehost
[remote] $ cat > /tmp/test.txt
testing
newline
^D[remote] $ echo another cmd
another cmd
[remote] $ ^D
```

which will create a new file `/tmp/test.txt` with the content "testing\nnewline\n", then run another command and terminate the ssh session.

I know that the ascii value for the EOT (end of transmission character) is `0x04`. So I thought I could emulate this by running:

```bash
$ echo "cat > /tmp/test.txt\ntesting\nnewline\n\x04echo another command\n" | ssh -tt remotehost
```

This seems to work in that it properly sends the commands, but it gets stuck when the end of file character should end the cat command. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `echo` builtin in bash doesn't do backslashed escapes by default, you must specify `-e`. In general `printf` is more robust and more portable. But even fixing that, sending _any_ control character fails for me e.g. `printf 'xxd<<<"a\x09b"\n' | ssh -tt ...` _sends_ a command line clearly including tab, but echoes and executes it without. Note your session could instead use a heredoc `command <<XYZ \n blah \n XYZ \n` and that DOES work over ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@dave_tompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085). Your comment made me realize I should check timings, and use printf. The following command works:

```bash
(printf 'cat > /tmp/test.txt\n'; 
 sleep 2; 
 printf 'testing\nnewline\n\x04'; 
 sleep 1; 
 printf 'echo another command\n\x04') | ssh -tt ...
```

An alternative solution is to use a here doc in the call to the `cat` command.